# How to convert serialized form to json format which having a list of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, forms

Here is my form:

```
<form>
 <input type="text" value="value1a" name="parentobject.childobject[0].field1"/>
 <input type="text" value="value2a" name="parentobject.childobject[0].field2"/>
 <input type="text" value="value3a" name="parentobject.childobject[0].field3"/>

 <input type="text" value="value1b" name="parentobject.childobject[1].field1"/>
 <input type="text" value="value2b" name="parentobject.childobject[1].field2"/>
 <input type="text" value="value3b" name="parentobject.childobject[1].field3"/>
</form>
```

when i used JSON.stringify($('form').serializeArray()), the value converted to json but not my expected result.

output after using JSON.stringify($('form).serializedArray())

```
{
 "parentobject.childobject[0].field1" : "value1a"
 "parentobject.childobject[0].field2" : "value2a"
 "parentobject.childobject[0].field3" : "value3a"
 "parentobject.childobject[1].field1" : "value1b"
 "parentobject.childobject[1].field2" : "value2b"
 "parentobject.childobject[1].field3" : "value3b"
}
```

and here is my expected result :

```
 {
    "parentobject": {
        "childobject": [
            {
                "field1": "value1a",
                "field2": "value2a",
                "field3": "value3a"
           },
            {
                "field1": "value1b",
                "field2": "value2b",
                "field3": "value3b"
            }
    ]
}
```

}

I hope someone could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should change the name of your inputs to field1, field2 ...

Comment: its a list. changing the name i guess is not the solution.

Comment: then don't use serialize, you need to hard code the method.

Comment: is there any option(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`eval()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function

```
var parentobject = {
    childobject: [{}, {}]
}
var arr = $('form').serializeArray();
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
eval(arr[i].name+"='"+arr[i].value+"'");
}
alert(JSON.stringify(parentobject))
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0v62hL7p/3/)

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/vorj5o1b/1/

`serializeArray()` only gets the `name` and `value` attributes of the fields in a single object. If you want to customise the output you get, you need to write your own function, so you can create your own custom array and call `stringify` on the custom array.

```
var myArray = [];

var fields = $("#f").serializeArray();
var obj = {};
var childObj = {};
var firstIndex = 0;

jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
    var parentName = field.name.split('.')[0];
    var childName = field.name.split('.')[1].split("[")[0];
    var childIndex = parseInt(field.name.split('.')[1].split("[")[1].split("]")[0]);
    var fieldName = field.name.split('.')[2];

    if (!obj[parentName]){ //If obj doesn't have the parentName object, create it.
        obj[parentName] = {};
    }

    if (!obj[parentName][childName]){ //if obj[parentName] doesn't have an array yet, create it
        obj[parentName][childName] = [];
    }

    if (firstIndex !== childIndex){ //when it moves from [0] to [1]
        firstIndex = childIndex;
        obj[parentName][childName].push(childObj); //push childObj to obj array
        childObj = {};
    }

    childObj[fieldName] = field.value;
    if (i == fields.length - 1){ //needs an extra if here to add the final childObj
         obj[parentName][childName].push(childObj);
    }
});

myArray.push(obj); //use custom array


var myString = JSON.stringify(myArray); //stringify custom array
console.log(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `serializeArray` method will not parse your field names to derive a hierarchical structure; you will have to code that manually, but it isn't too diffuclt. If you have a well-defined format, you can try something like the code below. If you need a more generic solution allowing for multiple levels of nesting, and different parent names, then you will need to build something more full-featured.

```js
$(function() {
    
    var $form = $("form");
    var regex = /.*childobject\[(\d)\].*/;
    var rgxForField = /.*childobject.*(field\d)/;
    var obj = {"parentobject" : {} };
    var childObjects = [];
    obj["parentobject"]["childobject"] = childObjects;

    $form.find("input[name^='parentobject.childobj']").each(function() {
        var idx = parseInt(this.name.match(regex)[1], 10);
        if (!childObjects[idx]) childObjects[idx] = {};
        var fieldName = this.name.match(rgxForField)[1];
        childObjects[idx][fieldName] = this.value;
    });
    console.log(obj);
    $form.after($("<div/>", { text: JSON.stringify(obj)}));
    $form.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" value="value1a" name="parentobject.childobject[0].field1"/>
 <input type="text" value="value2a" name="parentobject.childobject[0].field2"/>
 <input type="text" value="value3a" name="parentobject.childobject[0].field3"/>

 <input type="text" value="value1b" name="parentobject.childobject[1].field1"/>
 <input type="text" value="value2b" name="parentobject.childobject[1].field2"/>
 <input type="text" value="value3b" name="parentobject.childobject[1].field3"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @Werd No problem! If this, or any other answer, helped you solve your problem you should [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205949) to show that the issue was resolved, and help other folks find it in future (plus it gives a little credit to the person who answered).